# How to split a column into multiple rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS table that I imported from Oracle with two fields. `SYSTEMID` and `T_BLOB`.

Inside the `T_BLOB` field there is data:

```
2203 Mountain Meadow===========OSCAR ST===========Zephyrhill Road
```

(why they are delimiting with equal signs I do not know nor do I know who to ask).

I'm new to SAS and I'm being asked to split `T_BLOB` field into multiple rows in a table called `rick.split_blob`. I tried Google but I can't find the exact example. I'm trying to get the output to look like:

```
SYSTEM_ID          T_BLOB
GID_1              2203 Mountain Ave
GID_1              OSCAR ST
GID_1              Zephyrhill Road
```

Can anyone help me with how to code this?

Comment: Hi; welcome to the site.  Please take a look at [ask] and the [help], and let's see if we can get your question into a bit better form so you get the best possible answer.  First of all, you should specify how you're coding this - data step, SQL, etc.?  Second, you should show us **your best attempt**, even if you're not really sure how you should do it, so we have some idea of where to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Is the list of `=` always the same length?  If not is the length of the text plus the length of `=` always the same?  That is does the second value, in this case `OSCAR ST` , always start at the same location in the string? Can the values ever contain an `=` character?

Answer (score 1):

If none of the values ever contain `=` then you can just use the `scan()` function.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  length T_BLOB_VALUE $200 ;
  do i=1 by 1 until(t_blob_value=' ');
     t_blob_value=scan(t_blob,i,'=') ;
     if i=1 or t_blob_value ne ' ' then output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
data rick.split_blob (keep=SYSTEM_ID T_BLOB_SUB rename=(T_BLOB_SUB=T_BLOB));
set orig_dataset;

T_BLOB_TRANS = tranwrd(T_BLOB,"===========","|");
do i = 1 to countw(T_BLOB_TRANS,"|");
   T_BLOB_SUB = scan(T_BLOB,i,"|");
   output;
end;
run;
```

What I'm trying to do is first translate the odd string of equals signs to a simple pipe to avoid counting them as consecutive delimiters. Then we determine how many "words" (really - delimited strings) there are in T_BLOB_TRANS so we know how many times to run the DO loop. Finally we read everything between each delimiter and output it to a new T_BLOB variable for each new word.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you'll want to use a combination of the "scan" function and the "output" statement (with countw to get you the number of words if it is variable). Scan returns the nth word where you can specify the delimiter.  Output outputs a record.  So, for example, you can say

```
do i=1 to countw(line);
    newvar = scan(line,i);
    output;
end;
```