# SAS: How to replace delimit and split column to multiple rows?

Tags: sas

I have just started to learn SAS programming and I'm trying to experiment with replacing a phrase "@@@@" with "|" before splitting the cell into multiple rows in SAS Studio.

I have created an example below for this experiment. It was reference from [How to split a column into multiple rows in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639377/how-to-split-a-column-into-multiple-rows-in-sas) but I couldn't get it to work. The SYSTEM_ID column is printing well but the ITEM_LIST is not splitting.

My current output is as follows:
[image]

Here's my current code. Please help.

```
data example1;
    input SYSTEM_ID $ ITEM_LIST $ 5-50 ;
    datalines;
    ID_1 Apple Juice @@@@ Orange @@@@ Banana Milk
    ;
run;


data example2 (keep=SYSTEM_ID ITEM_LIST_SUB rename=(ITEM_LIST_SUB=ITEM_LIST));
    set example1;
    
    ITEM_LIST_TRANS = tranwrd(ITEM_LIST,"@@@@","|");
    do i = 1 to countw(ITEM_LIST_TRANS,"|");
       ITEM_LIST_SUB = scan(ITEM_LIST,i,"|");
       output;
    end;
run;

proc print data = example2;run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small problems to your otherwise fine solution :-)

1. You reference ITEM_LIST in the Scan Function instead of ITEM_LIST_TRANS
2. In your example data, your data is indented, so ID_1 becomes part of ITEM_LIST.

See if this works for you

```
data example1;
input SYSTEM_ID $ ITEM_LIST $ 5-50 ;
datalines;
ID_1 Apple Juice @@@@ Orange @@@@ Banana Milk
;
run;


data example2 (keep=SYSTEM_ID ITEM_LIST_SUB rename=(ITEM_LIST_SUB=ITEM_LIST));
    set example1;
    
    ITEM_LIST_TRANS = tranwrd(ITEM_LIST,"@@@@","|");
    do i = 1 to countw(ITEM_LIST_TRANS,"|");
       ITEM_LIST_SUB = scan(ITEM_LIST_TRANS,i,"|");
       output;
    end;
run;

proc print data = example2;run;
```

**Result:**

```
Obs SYSTEM_ID ITEM_LIST 
1   ID_1      Apple Juice 
2   ID_1      Orange 
3   ID_1      Banana Milk
```

Comment: oh my god! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DLMSTR will allow direct read.

```
data example1;
   infile cards dlmstr='@@@@' missover;
   input SYSTEM_ID $ @;
   length item $50;
   do until(missing(item));
      input item @;
      if not missing(item) then output;
      end;
   datalines;
ID_1 Apple Juice @@@@ Orange @@@@ Banana Milk
ID_2 Apple Juice @@@@ Orange @@@@ Banana Milk @@@@ Apple Juice @@@@ Orange @@@@ Banana Milk
;
run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]